# who is faster hashmap.get or treemap.get in java

Tags: java, collections

somewhere i read the `HashMap.get(object)` is faster than `TreeMap.get(object)`. but my question is why he is faster even both of will work on hashing function while retrieving `object`.

Comment: `TreeMap` doesn't use hashing.

Comment: Maybe look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057430/treemap-or-hashmap-faster

Answer (score 8):

`TreeMap` is a binary search tree implementation of the `Map` interface. Therefore any lookup operation requires `O(logN)` time.

On the other hand, `HashMap` uses the `hashCode()` of the key to locate the bin that contains the key in constant time. Since each bin has an expected number of entries bound by a small constant, lookup requires `O(1)` time, which is faster than `O(logN)`.

Answer (score 2):

As simple as, `HashMap` `put / get` method uses the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method, whereas `TreeMap` use the some comparison mechanism using `Comparable or Comparator`.

One more point,

`HashMap` is more time-efficient. A `TreeMap` is more space-efficient.