# When to use TreeMap instead of HashMap

Tags: java, collections

I require a map that supports 3 operations: "insert", "remove" and "iterate in sorted order". This is exactly the interface of `TreeMap` in Java. That being said it can also be implemented by using a `HashMap` and sorting it every time before iteration. To analyze the different approaches, lets say I perform `n` inserts and `m` removes, 'r' reads and then iterate.

With `TreeMap` we have the following implementation:

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tm = Maps.newTreeMap();
for (int i=0;i<n;++i) {tm.put(i, 2*i);} // O(n*log(n))
for (int i=0;i<m;++i) {tm.remove(i);} // O(m*log(m))
for (int i=0;i<r;++i) {tm.get(i);} // O(r*log(n-m))
for (Integer i : tm) {print(i);} // O(n-m)
```

All told we have a total run time of `O(n*log(n) + m*log(m) + r*log(n-m))`

With `HashMap` we have the following implementation:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = Maps.newHashMap();
for (int i=0;i<n;++i) {hm.put(i, 2*i);} // O(n)
for (int i=0;i<m;++i) {hm.remove(i);} // O(m)
for (int i=0;i<r;++i) {hm.get(i);} // O(r)
List<Integer> sortedList = Lists.newArrayList(hm.keySet()); // O(n-m)
Collections.sort(sortedList); // O((n-m)*log(n-m))
for (Integer i : sortedList) {print(i);} // O(n-m)
```

All told we have a total run time of `O((n-m)*log(n-m))`.

For all `n,m O(n*log(n) + m*log(m) + r*log(n-m)) > O((n-m)*log(n-m))`.

My question therefore is, what is the use case where a `TreeMap` is better than a `HashMap`? Is it only better if you need to iterate over the map many (let's say `k`) times (in which case, if `k` is >> `log(n)` the run time for `TreeMap` will be `O(k*(n-m))` whereas for `HashMap` will be `O(k*(n-m)*log(n-m)))`? Regardless, if you are only performing `O(log(n))` iterations (this does sound like such a sane use case), `HashMap` will outperform `TreeMap`. Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302371/which-data-structure-would-you-use-treemap-or-hashmap-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329358/treemap-or-hashmap

Comment: That is for a specific use case. My point is, does there exist a use case where TreeMap is better than HashMap.

Comment: The second question just explains the difference. I know the difference between the two kinds of Map. I want to know why TreeMap exists if it is always less efficient.

Comment: If you need to iterate from one specific entry onwards, then you should use the `TreeMap`.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Have you tried to read accepted answers in the linked questions? [Answer by Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/a/302378/451518) mentions `hash-then-sort` approach. [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5329585/451518) presents a use case for treemap - dictionary that is looked up thousands times after each update.

Comment: Not true! It is better to copy the map into a list and sort it.

Comment: Jon Skeet's answer claims that the only benefit of TreeMap is code readability. If that is true then you could implement TreeMap as a HashMap whose iterator sorts the collection on construction.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Just be aware that all collection views are *write-through* so if you copy everything into an array and sort it, you'll have a lot of work to do to maintain those semantics.

Comment: Yeah, I don't like the iterator idea very much either. I'm just saying that if the only reason to use TreeMap is that the usage of HashMap is unreadable (if much more efficient). I think the correct solution would be to make HashMap more readable and not accept the performance hit.

Comment: I would certainly *not* prefer `HashMap` just for readability. Proper code design can easily provide readability in any case.

Comment: @BenjyKessler Marko Topolnik's answer already provided nice use case for TreeMap: lookup by range. `HashMap` can only search for exact match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course there exist such use cases. In all read-heavy settings you have the advantage of sorting only once, during insertion. The majority of use cases *are* read-heavy, contrary to the assumptions of your question.

An even greater advantage is offered by the `TreeMap` when you need to extract submaps with an upper or lower bound on the key, find the minimum or maximum keys, or find keys closest to a given key. The interface `NavigableMap` is dedicated to these operations.

Comment: I edited my question to take into account reads. Reads in a HashMap are O(1) whereas in TreeMaps they run in O(log(n)).

Comment: We are discussing iteration here, so by "read" I mean "iterate over the map".

Comment: Is that true? What application iterates over a Map more often then inserts, removes and gets? I think get will be the most common operation, not iteration. If iteration was the most common operation then you are starting off with an O(k*n) > O(n^2) algorithm which is already unwieldy.

Comment: I can see why NavigableMap is useful, and if you want to implement it using a tree then that's fine. My question is why is TreeMap useful.

Comment: `TreeMap implements NavigableMap`.

Comment: In one sentence you refer to the whole *application*, then bait-and-switch to an *algorithm*. An application serves requests and typically it serves many requests by referring to the  state built up in a `TreeMap`, which gets updated occasionally.

Comment: OK, I will grant that for ranges it is useful but it should state in the documentation that this class is only useful if you need to manage ranges.

Answer (score 2):

An obvious use case is when you want to sort the map according to some `Comparator` definition. It's not always about performance.

Comment: OP has already covered that: use `HashMap` and sort before iteration.

Comment: You can sort `map,keySet()` with your custom comparator.

Comment: My point is that the OP is focusing just on the performance aspects. In some cases, it's not performance that is the overarching requirement but rather holding the data in some ordered way.

Comment: Nobody cares how you *hold* the data; we care about what you can *do* with it. If i gave you an implementation which had `HashMap` internally and used array sorting before returning a `keySet`, you would be as happy with it as with a `TreeMap`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I don't think you can see the wood from the trees here.

Comment: I find your comment unconstructive. You have just expressed an opinion without contributing any further arguments.